# Would vs should when used to make a polite request

Tags: word-usage

I know the differences between would and should and their use, in general. Yet, both of them can be used to make a polite request:

> I [would](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/would) like to meet him…(definition #4)
>
> I [should](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/should) like to meet him…(definition #6)

According to [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+should+like+to+meet%2CI+would+like+to+meet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20should%20like%20to%20meet%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20would%20like%20to%20meet%3B%2Cc0), there is a tendency for *should* to be on the decrease while *would* is on the increase.

I wonder whether the use of *should* when making a polite request would look now old fashioned or archaic. Nowadays, do people still use it?

Comment: The grammar of these sentences indicates a passive "hint hint" to the recipient than perhaps a more direct request in the form of a question. I haven't heard *I should like to meet him* in conversation. (Doesn't mean it isn't being said, just that it sounds a bit pretentious.)

Comment: To me, *should* always has a *flair of ordering* or something mandatory. *Would* has been polite to me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should (in this context) is old fashioned nowadays and would has definitly taken over. Would is used a lot more than should (in this context) in modern speech.